# Filtering ListView.builder output using a List of strings

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app with a screen that has some ListViews with items.

Each ListView shows items from model `Caso`:

```
List<Caso> casoDeTodosFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Caso>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Caso.fromJson(x)));

String casoToJson(List<Caso> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Caso {
  Caso(
      {required this.id,
      required this.titulo,
      required this.descripcion,
      required this.temaId,
      required this.subtemaId,
      required this.fecha_alta,
      required this.fondoTema,
      required this.tema,
      required this.subtema,
      required this.autor,
      required this.autor_alias,
      required this.autor_avatar,
      required this.codigo_caso});

  String id;
  String titulo;
  String descripcion;
  String temaId;
  String subtemaId;
  String fecha_alta;
  String fondoTema;
  String tema;
  String subtema;
  String autor;
  String autor_alias;
  String autor_avatar;
  String codigo_caso;

  factory Caso.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Caso(
        id: json["id"],
        titulo: json["titulo"],
        descripcion: json["descripcion"],
        temaId: json["temaId"],
        subtemaId: json["subtemaId"],
        subtema: json["subtema"],
        tema: json["tema"],
        fecha_alta: json["fecha_alta"],
        fondoTema: json["fondoTema"],
        autor: json["autor"],
        autor_avatar: json["autor_avatar"],
        autor_alias: json["autor_alias"],
        codigo_caso: json["codigo_caso"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "titulo": titulo,
        "descripcion": descripcion,
        "temaId": temaId,
        "subtemaId": subtemaId,
        "tema": tema,
        "subtema": subtema,
        "fecha_alta": fecha_alta,
        "fondoTema": fondoTema,
        "autor": autor,
        "autor_avatar": autor_avatar,
        "autor_alias": autor_alias,
        "codigo_caso": codigo_caso
      };
}
```

Here you have the code for the ListView:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: refresh,
        child: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchCasosTodosLoUltimo(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<dynamic>? filteredList = snapshot.data as List;

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: filteredList.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                    Caso caso = filteredList![index];

                    return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: CardCasos(
                          caso: caso,
                        ));
                  },
                );
              }

              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ));
```

Each `Caso` item has a field called `tema`

The app user can filter the items to be shown depending on `tema` string.

In the app there is a `List<String>` called `listaSuscripciones` defined in a Provider instance.

In this case:

```
listaSuscripciones = [Crónica negra, Recursos, Rutas mágicas]
```

I need to show all `Caso` items that have on `tema` field  one of the strings contained in `listaSuscripciones`.

For example, if a `Caso` item has as `tema` value the string `Crónica negra` it should be shown, else it must be removed from the ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
List<dynamic>? filteredList = snapshot.data as List;
```

you could write

```
filteredList = filteredList.where((caso) => listaSuscripciones.contains(caso.tema)).toList();
```

Comment: Nice and clean solution, it works fine